# Python, looping over list of urls to parse html content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the `html` source of url:

```
<h1>Queue &lt;&lt;hotspot-00:26:BB:05:BB:10&gt;&gt; Statistics </h1>
<ul>
  <li>Source-addresses: 10.10.1.130
  <li>Destination-address: ::/0
  <li>Max-limit: 1.02Mb/2.04Mb (Total: <i>unlimited</i>)
  <li>Limit-at: 1.02Mb/2.04Mb (Total: <i>unlimited</i>)
  <li>Last update: Mon Sep 23 21:41:16 2019

</ul>
```

and here's my code:

**Note** that `links` is list of `urls`

```
for link in links:
    page = requests.get(link).text
    sp1 = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").findAll('h1')
    sp2 = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").findAll('li')
    print(sp1,sp2)
```

**Current OUTPUT**

```
[<h1>Queue &lt;&lt;hotspot-00:26:BB:05:BB:10&gt;&gt; Statistics </h1>] [<li>Source-addresses: 10.10.1.130
  <li>Destination-address: ::/0
  <li>Max-limit: 1.02Mb/2.04Mb (Total: <i>unlimited</i>)
  <li>Limit-at: 1.02Mb/2.04Mb (Total: <i>unlimited</i>)
  <li>Last update: Tue Sep 24 00:27:05 2019
```

Trying to edit my code to get the following output.

```
hotspot-00:26:BB:05:BB:10, Limit-at: 1.02Mb/2.04Mb (Total: <i>unlimited
```

Comment: What is printed at `print(sp1,sp2)`? Edit that into your answer.

Comment: @KevinWelch it's there already. refresh for seeing the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to create two BeautifulSoup objects. As for your question:

```py
import re

for link in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    header = soup.find('h1').text
    header = re.sub(r'.*<<(.*)>>.*', r'\g<1>', header)
    limit = [elem.text.strip() for elem in soup.find_all('li') if re.search(r'^Limit-at:', elem.text)][0].split('\n')[0]
    print(header, limit)
```

I used the html you provided to test the above solution.

So you're getting lists there because you are using `find_all` which always returns a list.

For the header I used `find` same thing but it only returns the first match. Then I do some regex substitution to remove all but the desired portion of the header test.

For the limit things are a little trickier because it's in a nested `li` element. So loop through all of the `li` elements adding the one whose text attribute begins with 'Limit-at:'. Because that'll be a list I grab the 0 element, splitting that on the new line character, this produces a new list. Then grab the zero element of that to get rid of the 'Last Update' portion of that text.

Comment: got `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

Comment: See edited answer. Forgot to grab `text` from the `header = soup.find` line

Comment: OP deleted comment but asked about matching &lt; instead of <. You would just need to swap `<<` and `>>` with `&lt;&lt;` and `&gt;&gt;` respectively in the first parameter of `re.sub`.

Comment: it's works fine but if it `<h1>Queue &lt;hs-&lt;hotspot1&gt;&gt; Statistics </h1>` so output will be `Queue <hs-<hotspot1>> Statistics `

Comment: You will likely need a more complicated regular expression if the data is not consistent with the example you provided in your qguestion. I recommend checking out the docs for python's `re` module (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) and making use of any number of online regular expression testers. Try somethings and edit your post or create a new one if you're having trouble.

Comment: your answer is already works fine on all the data . only one line have the issue which i mentioned above. i tried with `header = re.sub(r'.*&lt;&lt;(.*)&gt;&gt;.*', r'\g<1>', header)` but it's giving different output.

Comment: i did found it. `.&lt;([^&]*)&gt;`

Comment: I'm happy you arrived at a great solution!